How do I remove this sink faucet handle?
I tried to remove this handle to soak it in vinegar because buildup of gunk has made it difficult to turn. Little did I suspect I wouldn’t be able to remove this.
The handle itself doesn’t appear to have a set screw or a cap or anything to reveal how to remove it. The underside has a nut threaded onto it that can’t be removed because the threads only go so far and there’s a valve sticking out of the side anyway. Does anyone know the secret?


pop out the top, under it is a nut

Remove the cap with the "C" on it.  It may look like it doesn't come off, but it does.  You will need a very small flat blade screwdriver and a lot of patience.
When the cap is off there will be a screw that can be removed. Then the handle can be pulled off.  That could take some effort too.  Don't pull to the side, pull straight up.
You can then clean and reassemble.

Try as I might, I could not get the C off.  I stopped short of using tools in a way that would have marred or broken it as the whole point was not to have to replace it.  As it turns out, mucking around with the shut-off valves during this has made the valves leak, so I am probably just going to get a new faucet and have a plumber change out the shut-off valves for quarter-turns and put in the new faucet.  Thanks though!  I suspect you're correct, and if I decide for sure to replace it, I'll bring the fury and try to get that cap off, no holds barred.

Some faucets with lever handles use the lever itself as the set-screw that holds the handle on. Try to unscrew the lever (counter-clockwise if looking at the end of the lever). It may require pliers if it's old and/or corroded.

I applied as much pressure as I could without using a tool, and no dice.  To use a tool would've marred it in a way that would have warranted replacement, and if I'm going that far, I'll just have a plumber do it.  Thanks for the tip though!
